# Combine graphs created by the fixest package

Tags: r, plot, fixest

I am trying to combine different graphs created by the fixest package.

```
library("fixest")
library("ggpubr")


data(base_did)
base_inter = base_did

est_did = feols(y ~ x1 + i(period, treat, 5) | id+period, base_inter)
pl1 <- iplot(est_did)
pl2 <- coefplot(est_did)



plot_list <- list(pl1, pl2)
combined_plot <- ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list, ncol = 2)
```

But I'm getting :

```
"Warning messages:
1: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
2: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
```

I tried converting the output from iplot() and coefplot() before passing them to ggarrange. I used   as.grob() but it returned an empty object.

Anyone know how to combine those graphs please ?

Edit:
The best way I've found for now is to use par, but I cannot save the graphs for later use.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
iplot(est_did)
coefplot(est_did)
iplot(est_did)
coefplot(est_did)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

I tried saving the graphs with :

```
iplot(est_did)
pl1 <- recordPlot()

coefplot(est_did)
pl2 <- recordPlot()

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
replayPlot(pl1)
replayPlot(pl2)
replayPlot(pl1)
replayPlot(pl2)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

But when I display them, they just are just 1 graph at a time, ignoring the par command (probably because the graph was created before the par command actually came in).